# bash script not working as expected when executed with cron

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I have the following bash script that works as expected when I manually run it

```
#!/bin/bash

result=$(curl http://myip.com)
echo "$result"
```

I have created the following cron

```
*/5 * * * * ./root/script.sh > /root/script.result
```

The file "script.result" does get created, but it's blank. Any idea what is wrong that the script produces no output when executed by cron?

Comment: I suggest to add full path to script.sh.

Comment: I am using the full path, It's `./root/script.sh`

Comment: Not setting the `SHELL` as `/bin/bash` in the cron, using just the interpreter as `#!/bin/bash` won't work. The cron doesn't run by default in the `bash`  shell

Comment: Set `SHELL=/bin/bash` in the line above your cron job

Comment: @Inian, thanks Inian, so any O.S cron will not have `bash` even bash system also? Could you please do let me know here, it is good learning to know about this command.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: `cron` runs in a minimalist environment, with a different `$PATH`

Comment: Try to use full path for your curl command.

Comment: Change your cron entry to `*/5 * * * * ./root/script.sh > /root/script.result 2> /root/script.errors` . Tell us what the errors file contains after the cron entry runs.